# Why do our eyes perceive changes in apparent position of stars as twinkling?

Tags: visible-light, astronomy, refraction, atmospheric-science, stars

Okay, so we all know that the changes in refractive index leads to continuous changes in star's apparent position but then why don't we see them moving up and down rather than brighten and dim in quick succession?

Comment: I suspect you observed both (a) minute changes in apparent position and (b) intensity variation of a star.  (b) could be due to the variation of density of air leading to variation in absorption of light leading to variation in star's intensity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The changes in apparent position do occur, but the apparent movement will be too small for your eye to detect.

And the changes are not coherent.  Think of someone with a funhouse mirror.  Instead of them gently turning the mirror one way or the other so you see an image shifting around, they're vibrating the mirror.  The image stays mostly in one place, but with constant distortions.

At times, the distortion appears to shrink the image.  This corresponds with less of the image being directed to your eye at that time, and would cause the apparent dimming of a luminous object.  At other times the image is larger and would show a case where a luminous object would appear brighter.